# How can a Windows Service determine its ServiceName?

Tags: c#, windows-services, service

I've looked and couldn't find what should be a simple question:

**How can a Windows Service determine the ServiceName for which it was started?**

I know the installation can hack at the registry and add a command line argument, but logically that seems like it *should* be unnecessary, hence this question.

I'm hoping to run multiple copies of a single binary more cleanly than the registry hack.

**Edit**:

This is written in C#.  My apps *Main()* entry point does different things, depending on 
command line arguments:

- Install or Uninstall the service.  The command line can provide a non-default
  ServiceName and can change the number of worker threads.
- Run as a command-line executable (for debugging),
- Run as a "Windows Service".  Here, it creates an instance of my *ServiceBase*-derived
  class, then calls *System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(instance);*

Currently, the installation step appends the service name and thread count to the *ImagePath* in the registry so the app can determine it's ServiceName.

Comment: You didn't mention what language you have written the service with.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=387024

Here is a WMI solution.  Overriding the *ServiceBase.ServiceMainCallback()* might also work, but this seems to work for me...

```
    protected String GetServiceName()
    {
        // Calling System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase::ServiceNamea allways returns
        // an empty string,
        // see https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=387024

        // So we have to do some more work to find out our service name, this only works if
        // the process contains a single service, if there are more than one services hosted
        // in the process you will have to do something else

        int processId = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service where ProcessId = " + processId;
        System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
            new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

        foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get()) {
            return queryObj["Name"].ToString();
        }

        throw new Exception("Can not get the ServiceName");
    }
```

Comment: For a 64-bit service will "select * From Win32_Service" still work?

Comment: Answering my own comment: yes this query works on WIN7 with 64-bit service.  Make sure you do not attempt this before theService.Run() is called!  Also - working folder is Windows\System32

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this, you've saved me so much pain.

Comment: @NVRAM did you try out the idea of overriding `ServiceBase.ServiceMainCallback()` in the meantime? I guess that would involve some tricky use of reflection to finger with that private delegate. Unfortunately the connect.microsoft link seems obsolete.

Comment: We tried this, and spontaneously it quit working on Windows Server 2012, for unknown reasons, on April 13, 2018. No kidding, on Friday the 13th it quit working. It throws some unintelligible COM error.
We ended up appending the service name to the registry entry's ImagePath value and it gets passed into Program->Main(string args[]) in the args array. Keys for services are in HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services.

Comment: Does it requires some priviledge?

Answer (score 7):

ServiceBase.ServiceName property gives the compile-time name of service. If you specify a different name when installing the service, then ServiceName attribute will not give correct name. So, I had to use below code to obtain the service name of my service.

It's an alternative (without using LINQ) to NVRAM's method:

```
/**
 * Returns the service name of currently running windows service.
 */
static String getServiceName()
{
    ServiceController[] scServices;
    scServices = ServiceController.GetServices();

    // Display the list of services currently running on this computer.
    int my_pid = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;

    foreach (ServiceController scTemp in scServices)
    {
        // Write the service name and the display name
        // for each running service.

        // Query WMI for additional information about this service.
        // Display the start name (LocalSytem, etc) and the service
        // description.
        ManagementObject wmiService;
        wmiService = new ManagementObject("Win32_Service.Name='" + scTemp.ServiceName + "'");
        wmiService.Get();

        int id = Convert.ToInt32(wmiService["ProcessId"]);
        if (id == my_pid)
        {
            return scTemp.ServiceName;
#if IS_CONSOLE
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("  Service :        {0}", scTemp.ServiceName);
            Console.WriteLine("    Display name:    {0}", scTemp.DisplayName);

            Console.WriteLine("    Start name:      {0}", wmiService["StartName"]);
            Console.WriteLine("    Description:     {0}", wmiService["Description"]);

            Console.WriteLine("    Found.......");
#endif
        }
    }
    return "NotFound";
}
```

I was incorrectly trying to obtain the name of windows service as first line in main() without first calling [ServiceBase.Run()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.run.aspx). We must register our executable as service using ServiceBase.Run() before obtaining its name.

Ref.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hde9d63a.aspx#Y320

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the service name is not available until ServiceBase.Run() is called. In retrospect, it seems obvious, but I was checking in the constructor, and still getting the compile-time name.

Comment: What if we are hosting multiple services inside the same exe? Will they be executed in different processes? If not then we need to tell the name of the service of the current thread instead of the current process. In that case how can we do that?

Answer (score 5):

Short version with Linq

```
  int processId = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
  ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service where ProcessId = " + processId);
  ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
  var serviceName = (string)collection.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().First()["Name"];
```

Comment: I don't understand how this works but it works lol. Thanks. How did you figure out how to do it? @Mahesh

Comment: I believe we need to dispose searcher and collection.

Answer (score 1):

By searching for a better solution i tried this:

```
string serviceName = "myDynamicServiceName";
string serviceBin = "path\\to\\Service.exe";
string configFile = "path\\to\\myConfig.xml";
string credentials = "obj= .\\mytestuser password= test";

string scCommand = string.Format( "sc create {0} start= auto binPath= \"\\\"{1}\\\" -ini={2} -sn={3}\" type= own{4}", serviceName, serviceBin, configFile , serviceName  ,credentials );
```

I passed the servicename and an configuration file to the binpath.
The service was installed by using the SC.exe (i don't use the installutil!)

On the service you can get the Commandline-Arguments

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args){
    string binpath = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(this.GetType()).Location).DirectoryName + "\\";
    System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter( binpath + "test.log");

    sw.WriteLine( binpath );

    string[] cmdArgs = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    foreach (string item in cmdArgs) {
        sw.WriteLine(item);
    }

    sw.Flush();
    sw.Dispose();
    sw = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a chicken-and-egg problem where I needed to know the service location before completing Service.Run()  (Service could be part of a client or server installation, installer named them appropriately, and I needed to detect which it was on startup)

I relied on the registry to get me the name.

```
public String IdentifySelfFromRegistry()
{
    String executionPath = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey services = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
            @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services");
    if (services != null)
    {
        foreach(String subkey in services.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            if (executionPath.Equals(ServicePathFromServiceKey(services.OpenSubKey(subkey))))
                return subkey;
        }
    }
    return String.Empty;
}

protected static String ServicePathFromServiceKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey serviceKey)
{
    if (serviceKey != null)
    {
        String exec = serviceKey.GetValue(ServicePathEntry) as String;
        if (exec != null)
            return exec.Trim('\"');
    }
    return String.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ServiceMain() entry point that every service executable must implement receives the ServiceName as its first input argument.

If you are writing your service using .NET, the ServiceMain() entry point is implemented by .NET for you.  The ServiceName is assigned when the service is installed using the ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceName property.  If you are trying to customize a .NET service to support dynamic ServiceName values, I have no clue how to access the actual ServiceName at runtime.

Comment: @Remy - it looks like ServiceMain is for C++ code ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685138%28VS.85%29.aspx ), I'm using C#.  @Isalamon - I believe you're mistaken, but if you can show how **SC** can be used, please post an answer with details.

Comment: Even .NET services have a ServiceMain() entry point, just one that .NET implements for you (the ServiceBase.ServiceMainCallback() method).  I just noticed that the ServiceBase.OnStart event has an args parameter.  I have not written services in .NET, but assuming ServiceBase does not strip out the first parameter provided by ServiceMain() (the ServiceName) when building up the args parameter, then you should be able to pull out the ServiceName from it.

Comment: Unfortunately, .NET does strip out the argument.  And the OnStart() parameters are only used when starting a service *interactively*.  Ref: http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework/2009-01/msg00073.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool IsServiceInstalled(string serviceName)
{
  // get list of Windows services
  ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();

  // try to find service name
  foreach (ServiceController service in services)
  {
    if (service.ServiceName == serviceName)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with this.ServiceName, if you're inside the service.cs?

i.e.:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Logger.Info($"{this.ServiceName} started on {Environment.MachineName}...");  
    }
```

Comment: This is not the same service name that appears in the Windows Services list :(

Comment: ServiceBase.ServiceName and ServiceInstaller.ServiceName are two different properties, but they should be the same. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller?view=netframework-4.7.1

Comment: When a service is started, the ServiceName property is not dynamically set by Windows or the .NET Framework. If your ServiceName property contains a value at runtime in OnStart(), it is more than likely because you explicitly set the value somewhere else. For example, the default project template for a Windows Service will set this.ServiceName = "Service1"; in the InitializeComponent() method of the Service1.Designer.cs file. However, that is not the value that I set in the ProjectInstaller.cs that is used with InstallUtil. So in other words, you cannot dynamically get the name this way.