# Application entry point static void main getting called multiple times in .NET

Tags: .net, service, static

There are 5 windows services which uses same exe. These are set as Automatic in SCM. When the server is restarted these windows services throw the error "windows service din't startup in timely manner". The issue is with the way the code has been written. To identify where the issue is i have written the EventView logging in the code but saw that the main entry point i.e static void main is getting called everytime SCM is trying to start the service. Below is the code

static class Program
    {
        /// 
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// 
        /// Original code with event logging
        static void Main()
        {
            GetAllServicesToRun();
        }

```
    private static void GetAllServicesToRun()
    {
        EventLog ev = new EventLog("");
        try
        {
            string msg = string.Empty;


            ev.Source = "STARTAPPLN";
            msg = "Appln start" + " at time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:fff");
            ev.WriteEntry(msg, EventLogEntryType.FailureAudit);
            TaskServiceConfig tsc = (TaskServiceConfig)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("TaskServiceConfigSection");
            IList<ServiceBase> ServicesToRun = new List<ServiceBase>();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var config in tsc.TaskServices)
            {
                Hashtable arguments = new Hashtable();
                arguments.Add("taskServiceName", ((TaskServices.ConfigSection.TaskServiceConfig.TaskServiceElement)config).Value);

                ev.Source = "ForLoop_" + i.ToString() + "_START";
                msg = "start For Loop_" + i.ToString() + " at time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:fff") + " :SN: " + arguments["taskServiceName"].ToString();
                ev.WriteEntry(msg, EventLogEntryType.FailureAudit);


                ServicesToRun.Add(new Service1(arguments));

                ev.Source = "ForLoop_" + i.ToString() + "_END";
                msg = "end For Loop_" + i.ToString() + " at time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:fff");
                ev.WriteEntry(msg, EventLogEntryType.FailureAudit);

                i = i + 1;
            }
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun.ToArray());
        }
```

Since main entry point is getting called multiple times SCM is marking the services as timeout because the initial start up is taking more than 30 sec. I can not change the registry setting to increase the start up time. My doubt is in such scenario the main entry point should not be called multiple times.

Comment: If your loop there is taking too long, can't you just move all that to a worker, and just have the service startup code : start the worker?

Comment: btw; you say there are 5 services at the "windows service" layer; that means you should *expect* the exe to be called 5 times - once per logical service - is that what the issue is here?

Comment: Yes Marc this is the issue. Main entry point should get executed once only..this is what i assume but it is getting called everytime SCM is trying to start the service. All 5 services share the same exe

Comment: then as I stated already (comment and answer), the problem here is that your expectation is incorrect. The fact that they share an exe is irrelevant; in fact, in many scenarios it is common to use the same exe to represent different named instances of the same software. The fact that they use the same exe ***does not matter***; they are fundamentally ***different*** services, and will be started independently. If you only want it to start once, then only register it as one service.

Answer (score 1):

> but saw that the main entry point i.e static void main is getting called everytime SCM is trying to start the service

Yes, that is normal; that is exactly what the windows service manager *does* to try to start the service

> My doubt is in such scenario the main entry point should not be called multiple times.

If you have it configured as 5 separate services in the windows service list, then it will be started 5 times - once per registration. If you want to know the service name on each exe separately, then [How can a Windows Service determine its ServiceName?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841790/how-can-a-windows-service-determine-its-servicename)