# How to pass arguments to installutil MyService.exe Parameter1 Parameter2

Tags: installutil

How to pass arguments to installutil MyService.exe Parameter1 Parameter2

I MyService is a windows service. I want to pass the arguments to this service.

Answer (score 4):

override the install method of ProjectInstaller class

```
public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
        {
              base.Install(stateSaver);
              string lParam1 = Convert.ToString(GetParam("Param1"));  

        }

        private object GetParam(string p)
        {
            try
            {
                if (this.Context != null)
                {
                    if (this.Context.Parameters != null)
                    {
                        string lParamValue = this.Context.Parameters[p];
                        if (lParamValue != null)
                            return lParamValue;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex )
            {

            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
```

and install the service using **`installutil /Param1=value path_to_your_exename`**

Answer (score 1):

First you need to insert an installer to your service. But I guess you're already over that. Otherwise please read this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-add-installers-to-your-service-application

As @Sumeshk mentioned you can pass arguments to this installer with the installutil like 
`installutil /Param1=value path_to_your_exename` and retrieve these informations in your installer code by `this.Context.Parameters`.

Now you want to pass these parameters as arguments to your service. The trick is to attach them to the `assemblypath` before the installation as you can see here:

[How to pass a parameter to a windows service once and for all at install instead of each start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488851/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-a-windows-service-once-and-for-all-at-install-instead)

Therefor you have to override the installer method `OnBeforeInstall`. Then you can manipulate the given assemblypath by attaching your parameters. Don't forget to call the base method `OnBeforeInstall` at the end:

```
protected override void OnBeforeInstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
    string oldPath = this.Context.Parameters["assemblypath"];
    string yourParam = this.Context.Parameters["Param1"];
    string pathWithParam = $"\"{oldPath}\" \"{yourParam }\"";
    this.Context.Parameters["assemblypath"] = pathWithParam;
    base.OnBeforeInstall(savedState);
}
```

Please note, to avoid problems with possible spaces in your parameter or the assembly path, you should frame these strings in double quotes. Seperate every parameter with a whitespace. If doing so, the `ImagePath` of your service in the registry will be composed of the path plus separated by a space your parameter. You can find this in the key `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<your service name>`

Now you can evaluate your parameter in your service in the `args` parameter of the method `OnStart`:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Param1: {args[0]}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have too little reputation to comment on @Rouvens post. I foremost have to thank him for his answer. However, I would like to make a small correction.

The arguments you register for `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<your service name>` through the installer component are NOT directly passed to `OnStart(string[] args)` as he claims.

Instead they follow in the constructor of the service:

```
public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    string myArgument;

    public MyService(string[] args)
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        
        this.myArgument= {args[0]}; // this is where you capture your argument
    }
}
```

Afterwards your have to pass these values without consideration for OnStart's arguments.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    BusinessLogicControl.Main(new string[] { myArgument});
}
```