# Windows Service Command line parameters with Automatic Start

Tags: c++, windows, service

I wrote a simple Windows service based on [this](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppWindowsService-cacf4948#content) sample. I need to pass a couple of parameters to the service, as command line parameters (reading the Service registry hive does not work on Windows7).
 I tried the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488851/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-a-windows-service-once-and-for-all-at-install-instead) but it does not work: when I add the parameters to the value in the `<MyService>\ImagePath` entry (i.e `"D:\MyService.exe" "-param1" "-param2"`) the service fails to start.
.

Comment: I successfully do this with `CreateService` by double quoting the full path of the executable and I'm not quoting the parameters (not sure if that matters or not).  Check the escaping in your string (is that backslash and your quotes in your example escaped correctly in the code?).  Maybe provide some of your code we can look at...

Comment: I notice that the main function (wmain) in the code you link to doesn't start the service if the first command-line argument begins with a dash or a forward slash.  Perhaps that's your problem?

Comment: I added a first command-line argument without a dash or a forward slash. The service now starts but no `args` are passed to the main function: `argc` is always 1.