# Install a Windows Service having parameters

Tags: .net, windows-services, installutil

I try to install a Windows Service having parameters.

I try to reproduce something like this:

[image]

but it seem impossible to install it like this :

```
InstallUtil.exe "C:\MyPath..\MyExe.ProcessorService.exe -service myParam"
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, [`InstallUtil.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/installutil-exe-installer-tool) does not support this.  It doesn't appear to have command line switches for adding parameters to the service start command.

It does appear you can do this via the `sc start` command from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488851/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-a-windows-service-once-and-for-all-at-install-instead) answer.  The `net start` command might even allow you to do it, too, based on [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/143367/how-to-start-a-service-with-certain-start-parameters-on-windows) answer.

Fundamentally, if you have a service named `Foo`, the registry key of interest is `ImagePath`:

```
[HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Foo]
"ImagePath":<PathToService>\MyService.exe Parameter1 Parameter2
```

If you following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195478/how-to-make-a-net-windows-service-start-right-after-the-installation/1195621#1195621) to have your service *install* itself from the command line (e.g., `<PathToService>\MyService.exe -install`), you should be able add the necessary logic after the `InstallService()` call to have the service update its `ImagePath` registry key with the necessary parameters.

HTH